# Config Maps to Connect Strings

Tags: java, azure, tomcat, kubernetes, database-connection

I have a rest api where I have the databases in azure and the application with docker + kubernetes, so alright.

I have more than 10 clients and each client owns a database, I did not want to have a docker image for each client, just have a base image where for each client would have a connect string, the proposed solution was to make a **setenv.sh** to make the connections

**setenv.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

dbuser="xxx@iafox"
dbpassword="mypassword"
dbconnectstring="jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.database.windows.net:1433;database=ts-demo1;user=xxx@iafox;password=mypassword;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;"
dburl="jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.database.windows.net:1433;database=ts-demo1;"

export CATALINA_OPTS=" ${SYSTEM_PROPS} -Ddbuser='${dbuser}' -Ddbpassword=${dbpassword} -Ddbconnectstring='${dbconnectstring}' -Ddburl='${dburl}'"
```

**server.xml**

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" connectionURL="${dbconnectstring}" driverName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" roleNameCol="role" userCredCol="password" userNameCol="login" userRoleTable="userRole" userTable="v_login"/>
```

Until then everything is working. But now I do not know the next step, if for every **setenv** that I create I will have a **configmap** in kubernetes, or if I will have all the connect strings in the same **setenv** .... I wanted a help in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set multiple environment variables from one `configMap` as documented [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#configure-all-key-value-pairs-in-a-configmap-as-container-environment-variables).

But I would recommend storing passwords and connection strings with sensitive information in a `secret`.

You can [reference Kubernetes secrets in a similar way](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables) to set the container's environment vars.

Comment: I had done 1 config map for each connect string and this worked, but I'll also analyze your suggestion, maybe it will be more portable. thank you!